# Why is it returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I want to store as the following method, and get the constant value, by querying using key to find value or by value to find the key

```
function my_reference() {
  return {
    30:'',
    31:'ERR591',
    32:'ERR761',
    33:'ERR671',
    34:'ERR551',

  };
}

console.log( my_reference[31], 
             my_reference.31, 
             my_reference().31,
             my_reference()[31]
);
```

Comment: because you need to execute a function hence why `my_reference()[31]` works

Comment: my_reference()['31']

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> my_reference[31],
> ```

Trying to read a property (which doesn't exist) of a function. The property is on the object that is the return value of *calling* the function.

> ```
> my_reference.31,
> ```

Trying to use a number as an identifier. This isn't allowed.

> ```
> my_reference().31,
> ```

Trying to use a number as an identifier. This isn't allowed.

> ```
> my_reference()[31]
> ```

This works

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute the function with `my_reference()` and after that access the property you want to.. but the keys in javascript objects are always strings:

```
console.log(my_reference()['31']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a function to store the references:

```
var reference = {
    30:'',
    31:'ERR591',
    32:'ERR761',
    33:'ERR671',
    34:''
};

console.log(reference[31]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call function if you want it to return result, function called by :

```
my_reference()
```

So the both first lines will not work because `my_reference` will return the function it self and not call it :

```
my_reference[31]
my_reference.31
```

The third also will not work `console.log(my_reference().31);` because attribute can't be numeric.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fixed code

```
function my_reference() {
  return {
    _30:'',
    _31:'ERR591',
    _32:'ERR761',
    _33:'ERR671',
    _34:'ERR551'
  };
}

var f = my_reference();

console.log(f["_31"]); 
console.log(f._31);
console.log(my_reference()._31);
console.log(my_reference()["_31"]);
```

**Variables can't be named with just numbers**
The first two should be the **returned object**